Hexagon button content does not show in XAML
I have created a button with a hexagonal shape. The hexagonal style is defined in a dictionary and is implemented correctly. However, the issue I am facing is that the button text is not showing anymore. I'm wondering if I need to add new text on top or if there is something missing in my style definition to display the text. Logically, when I stop applying the style, the text is shown again as it becomes a default button. Thank you. Below, I am providing the code from the dictionary and the button within the view.
Style Code of the button
<Style x:Key="HexagonButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Polygon x:Name="Hexagon" Points="25,0 75,0 100,43.3 75,86.6 25,86.6 0,43.3"
                         Fill="LightBlue"
                         Stroke="DarkBlue"
                         StrokeThickness="2"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- Cambiar el color del botón al pasar el cursor por encima -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter  TargetName="Hexagon" Property="Fill" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        <Setter  Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!-- Cambiar el color del borde al presionar el botón -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Hexagon" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

**Button implementation on view
**
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource HexagonButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Watch Now"/>
    </Button.Content>
 </Button>

I tried changing the way of calling the style, whether dynamic or static, but the issue persists. In other words, the style is called and the shape is implemented correctly, but the text does not appear. Thank you.

you need to add a ContentPresenter in the Template

All ContentControl are need a ContentPresenter in the ControlTemplate to display the Content. Button is a ContentControl.
